# Is it possible to use Web Bluetooth from a WebView?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying too use WebBluetooth from an Android WebView. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest update from chrome team,  Web Bluetooth API is now enabled in Chrome on Android, Chrome OS, and Mac. So you can't directly use these services in android web view. But if you use Chrome Custom Tabs in android, you will be able to do this.
[Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Comment: I can confirm Custom Tabs worked for me. Also as of 2-8-21 Web Bluetooth is still not supported in WebView. The new Custom Tabs  implementation guide is located here: https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/implementation-guide